# Firefox "html.css" destroy current page style, how to disable it?

Tags: css, firefox

The "html.css" is very mysterious to me, it always suddenly appear and suddenly disappear, when it appears, it always destroy my page style and keep sticky there until God knows when it disappears

Is there a way to disable it ? How?

Add: i found the problem appears not only in my system but also in my guest os, so i guess i have to found the cause and fix it as it may also appears in site visitors computer

Comment: What add-ons do you have installed? This might be caused by an add-on.

Comment: i use a couple of plugins, tab mix, foxproxy, foxclocks, dust-me, accuweather, toomanytabs...

Comment: And disabled all but this issue still exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html.css is default stylesheet of firefox. you can find more info about it [here](http://www.oppenheim.com.au/2008/07/06/how-to-view-firefoxs-default-internal-css-stylesheet/) and [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2004/09/15/emreallyem-undoing-htmlcss/)

and when you asked about disabling it , did you mean to over-ride the default behaviour ?

if yes, you can use reset the default style sheet,

there are several ways

- [Eric Meyer's reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
- [YUI reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)
- or create your own based on project requirements

Comment: I use 960's reset.css. I tried remove html.css, empty html.css, both crash firefox. They must be crazy to defaultly assign 'display:block' to <p>, even i override it in my css, there are many other abnormals and i don't want to write a css specially for the damn 'html.css', it's not the right way

Comment: @Edward The default is there to make sure that a page will display with semantic formatting when CSS is disabled or unavailable.  The defaults Firefox uses are not very different from those in other browsers.

Comment: @banzaimonkey, i really wish it works as other browsers. Chrome safari opera ie all have no this issue. I care firefox only because the best developer tools in it, firebug. I now have to use developer tools in chrome, which is not so convenient as firebug, to continue my developement

Comment: you can use firebuglite on Chrome. It's not too extensive as firebug for firefox but for normal things such as find elements,classes,ids and modify them it's great

Comment: @sotiris, just installed firebug lite, it's great! This is by far the best answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not trying to defend firefox's way of implementing this stuff, but what I've noticed is that html.css appears when something is wrong with the markup.

Recently I was figuring out whether a `<form>` element can be inside of a `<table>` if given a `display:table-row` (such code turned out to be invalid according to w3c validator).
While exploring the page using firebug I've mentioned that html.css appeared.
When get the `<form>` out of the `<table>` (so valid markup was back again) I could see no html.css anymore.